# Collection vs set in this textbook about category theory, and some related questions.

Tags: category-theory, definition

What is the meaning of collection in this context ? Is it here a synonym of set ?

Can someone please explain what the author means by "**A moment's though shows that, as sets of functions, these two sets are the same**."

Why are they the same ?

[image]

Here is the previous page for some more context:
[image]

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: Harold Simmons, [An Introduction to Category Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Category-Theory-Harold-Simmons/dp/0521283043/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404136888&sr=1-1&keywords=Harold+Simmons+An+Introduction+to+Category+Theory) (2011), page 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'collection', as I understand it, means something like 'things connected to each other in a way we intuitively understand but don't necessarily have a good mathematical definition for (and aren't going to worry about right now)'.

The comment about the two sets being the same is saying that, although we have two definitions of sets, the elements in them are exactly the same. If you take a map that is monotone by the presets definition, it is also monotone by the posets definition, and vice-versa.

Comment: So we cannot speak of sets of arrows ?

Comment: The word 'set' has a precise meaning in this context. Everyday language would see 'set' and 'collection' as synonymous, but when you are discussing the mathematical objects 'sets' it is more important to be careful about which word you use.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to category theory, so I was just wondering if such a concept as set of arrows exists at all? Is it correct to talk about set of arrows? Is there a reason why the author uses the term "collection of arrows" instead of "set of arrows" ? Or in this case it would be also precise to say "set of arrows"?

Comment: Yeah, the reason for saying collection rather than set is that some collections are too big to be sets. Some collections are proper classes, some collections are are even too big for that and I forgot what they are called.

Similarly, some of the function like objects in category theory may be too big to be functions (since functions are sets). So category theorists are also careful about what they call a function.